# Certbot DNS Bind Address?

Tags: centos, centos-7, network-interface, certbot

Is there a way to execute certbot such that the outgoing IP will be one of a set of interfaces on the machine instead of the default interface?

One of the messages certbot gives when using:

```
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns
```

is:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
NOTE: The IP of this machine will be publicly logged as having requested this
certificate. If you're running certbot in manual mode on a machine that is not
your server, please ensure you're okay with that.

Are you OK with your IP being logged?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
(Y)es/(N)o:
```

However, I'm running a server with multiple IP addresses with distinct PTR records for each and don't want the reverse DNS associated with some of the certs to be linkable to the others.

If there isn't a way to tell certbot itself which interface to use, is there a way within `Centos 7` to restrict a command to a particular interface such that it will bind there automatically on a per-execution basis (I still would like to be able to stick this into a cron job, with one for each address.)

Comment: If you have valid routes out to the world (or at least to the LE servers) you could perhaps play with your routing table before/after each cert request, changing the default route temporarily...

Comment: I'd like this to be a production-capable solution as opposed to a hack.  Can't have my routing tables going down twice a day for a few minutes as the certbot handles a few dozen potential renewals (the recommended times are midnight and noon with a 3600-second-max random interval thereafter for the actual start of checks.)